# Azure Date parsing issue in MSIToken

Tags: javascript, azure, function

**Describe the bug**

Azure App Service Environment MSI endpoint is returning a JWT token with an expires_on with "AM" in it. "5/15/2020 5:25:16 AM +00:00 
 Can any one can suggest me how to fix it.

**Code**:
Code:

```
`String kvUri = "https://abcvault.vault.azure.net";
SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
.vaultUrl(kvUri)
.credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
.buildClient();
//getting exception here
KeyVaultSecret retrievedSecret = secretClient.getSecret("secret_name");
String storageConnectionString = retrievedSecret.getValue();
```

**maven dependencies**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-beta.4</version>
</dependency> `
```

**Exception or Stack Trace**:

Failure Exception: IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse date time 5/15/2020 5:25:16 AM +00:00 Stack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22) at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.execute(JavaMethodExecutor.java:54) at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:53) at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33) at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10) at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45) at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Max retries 3 times exceeded. Error Details: Can't overwrite cause with com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: Cannot create any credentials with the current environment variables at com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy.lambda$attemptAsync$1(RetryPolicy.java:72) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88) at .....
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedConstructor.call(AnnotatedConstructor.java:124) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(StdValueInstantiator.java:283) ... 76 more [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException: Cannot construct instance of `com.azure.identity.implementation.MSIToken`, problem: Unable to parse date time 5/15/2020 5:25:16 AM +00:00 at [Source: {"access_token":"pNFuNYCQNTTbwx_hyr8s9UzQu7lD0wpnNuHiU9xdG2tdYDu5CHG2lr1f51hxIWFDEf6KUgBzXzk30ZsXIENb8VTko72_CPdjJkLcO_frI-7P8d_5TU-IbgnAef9Mb8Eru_SUdyRhZzYQ-vWajC9OEz1soDQdVkEBOaMbaSKtn4iiOEtgy0rp9TTRi5ZHdgrBng-MAWNrwjJUdCCNkHiIfnCrFq8JhrwxcPu6oLDTZIWQQvnfj9_-cae1b4yKIvLp3BCok79w9Cy0aYDCqZX07BDzfgRvS9zW7D4NCP4AVMJ9rSfklb-hl9Ybu_L5zvjy4xulI8k-INrEc61lk5A2Pg","expires_on":"5/15/2020 5:25:16 AM +00:00","resource":"https://vault.azure.net","token_type":"Bearer","client_id":"77979-2D5F-4209-A946-28B1CC46543E"}; line: 1, column: 1417]]

Comment: any luck in finding the solution?

Comment: looks related to this one https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/6949